# Using ImageMagick to merge a lot (100-1000) simple graphics rendered in Cairo (R wrapper)

Tags: r, animation, svg, imagemagick, gif

1. Rendering some very basic shapes (think Tic-Tac-Toe). As the simulation progresses, each “game board” is rendered into image file by graphics library (here, Cairo in R, but I don’t think that matters).
2. I have about 100 to 1000 frames. The Cairo wrapper I’m using can render to svg, raster rgba, pdf, png. I chose svg because it seems easy for import by ImageMagick.
3. Each svg I have is about 22KB.
4. Now, when I glob the full set of svgs (100 to 1000 range), the problem is that the space taken up as ImageMagick objects explodes. I’m seeing easily 8 to 16 GB for about 200 to 400 svgs only.
5. I then call ImageMagick::image_animate, ImageMagick::image_write to successfully generate an animated gif. The final gif is 2.8 MB for an input size of 200 svgs (each svg 22 KB).
6. 200 * 22 KB =~ 4 MB, so an output of 2.8MB is 3MB/4MB=75% compression.
7. However, these are super simple svg that’s literally something like Tic-Tac-Toe and whose discrete representation are at most 100 squares per image—should be super compact to represent as svg.

***Is this normal? Should I be seeing such huge memory-usage for simple svgs loaded into ImageMagick (albeit 100’s of svgs at a time).***

- should I be choosing other image format (e.g. png) as the file format for separate images to load into ImageMagick?
- there’s gotta be a way better compression for a bunch of simple square shapes. Even for import into ImageMagick object space, shouldn’t take-up 8 to 16+ GB...

Thanks kindly for any advice.

Comment: **ImageMagick** is a *raster* image processor, so it rasterises everything, including SVGs onto a grid before it does anything. That means that the 100-byte SVG that says *"draw a line from [0,0] to [1000,1000]" will cause **ImageMagick** to create a 1000x1000 image of RGB pixels at 16bits per sample, so your 100 bytes suddenly become 6MB on load. But your GIF is raster-based too, so you are going to have to do that anyway.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks so much. That answers my fundamental issue then. Feel free to post as answer and I will accept it.  Btw, is it possible to create a pipeline in Imagemagick where I stream in 10 svgs into object space at a time, then have them append into the imagemagick object image_animate’s output object ?  This should solve the memory issue.

Comment: You could consider using [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) for post-processing gif images. Besides optimizing size, you can for example stitch together several shorter animations to a large one with  the `--multifile` option.

Comment: @ccprog Thanks :)  I didn’t know about that at all. I think using such a program (implying a tool-chain using console and file-system as cache) may be best.